# jQuery: easy adaptable tooltips without the use of images and free for commercial uses

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

Is there a jquery tooltips plugin that does not use images, is free and might be used commercially and looks fancy (at least not just like a square, but like a bubble)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at qTip: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

Also qTip2 has already been launched...